# How would I write a SQL SELECT statement for this database table?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
TimeStamp                      ACW_TIME
2017-09-25T00:04:41      178
2017-09-25T00:09:41      181
2017-09-26T00:14:41      183
2017-09-26T00:19:41      184
2017-09-26T00:24:41      186
2017-09-27T00:29:42      188
2017-09-28T00:34:42      188
2017-09-28T00:39:41      188
```

In the 'TimeStamp' field I have 4 different dates of timestamps.

I need a SQL SELECT statement that will tell me how many times each day 'ACW_TIME' field value was greater than 180.

Can someone please help with this? This is totally rattling my brain going over SQL to figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: I'll throw a hint in here, you'll want to use GROUP BY CAST in your query

Comment: That is what I was trying to figure out that I want to CAST each timestamp to a day only and then group by those results but I am having difficulties with the syntax. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
select date(Timestamp), count(*) 
from 
tablename 
where 
ACW_TIME>180
GROUP BY date(Timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's GROUP BY and COUNT functions to achieve what you are asking.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM database_name.table_name WHERE ACW_TIME > 180 GROUP BY CAST (TimeStamp as DATE);
```

Essentially, instead of having the full timestamp we only want MySQL to consider the date in the stamp, and group by that.